# how do i insert a new item in an array inside an ob

Tags: javascript

```
var john = {

  billValues: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
  tipcalculation: function() {
    this.tipsForEachBill = [];
    this.tipsPlusBill = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < this.billValues.length; i++) {
      if (this.billValues[i] < 50) {
        this.tipsForEachBill.push(this.billValues[i] * 0.2);

      } else if (this.billValues[i] >= 50 && this.billValues[i] < 200) {
        this.tipsForEachBill.push(this.billValues[i] * 0.15);

      } else {
        this.tipsForEachBill.push(this.billValues[i] * 0.1);
      }
    }
  }
};


console.log(john.tipsForEachBill);
```

the result i get in the console is 'undefined'
i know there are other ways doin it but i need to know what wrong !!
why i can't push items into the array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that property doesn't exist until it gets created by calling `john.tipcalculation()` since that is the only place you have referenced it

```js
var john = {

  billValues: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
  tipcalculation: function() {
    this.tipsForEachBill = [];
    this.tipsPlusBill = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < this.billValues.length; i++) {
      if (this.billValues[i] < 50) {
        this.tipsForEachBill.push(this.billValues[i] * 0.2);

      } else if (this.billValues[i] >= 50 && this.billValues[i] < 200) {
        this.tipsForEachBill.push(this.billValues[i] * 0.15);

      } else {
        this.tipsForEachBill.push(this.billValues[i] * 0.1);
      }
    }
  }
};
// do the tip calculation
john.tipcalculation()
// now john.tipsForEachBill exists
console.log(john.tipsForEachBill);
```

Comment: Yep, got it, tanks

Answer (score 0):

If `tipcalculation` function hasn't run, the array `tipsForEachBill` will not have been created. See below example.

```js
const obj = {
    add: function () {
        this.b = [];
    }
};

console.log(obj.b);
obj.add();
console.log(obj.b);
```